# is the any way i can have my side bar nav sticky and the content boy overflow and scrolling

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a dashboard with a side nav bar and content inner secction but i am having challenges having it scrollabe. When i scroll the height of the side nav is affected and scrolls along with the inner conent section.

[[image: image below][1]]

The link to my dashboards with issues are

https://zifmcms.vercel.app/cms/podcasts

https://zifmcms.vercel.app/cms/newscorner

[image: I have attached image two below]

Below is my dashboard layout code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react'
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function AccountLayout(props) {
    const location = useLocation()
    const { window, children } = props;

    const setBgColor = (path) => {
        if (location.pathname === path) {
            return "bg-gray-700"
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-1 bg-gray-50">
            <div className="hidden portalSidebar bg-gray-900 md:flex md:w-64 md:flex-col">
                <div className="flex flex-col pt-8 overflow-y-auto">
                    <div className="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 px-4">
                        <a href="#" title="" className="">
                            <h3 className='logoText inline-flex'>
                                <span className='ml-5 mr-2'>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 7.5l16.5-4.125M12 6.75c-2.708 0-5.363.224-7.948.655C2.999 7.58 2.25 8.507 2.25 9.574v9.176A2.25 2.25 0 004.5 21h15a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V9.574c0-1.067-.75-1.994-1.802-2.169A48.329 48.329 0 0012 6.75zm-1.683 6.443l-.005.005-.006-.005.006-.005.005.005zm-.005 2.127l-.005-.006.005-.005.005.005-.005.005zm-2.116-.006l-.005.006-.006-.006.005-.005.006.005zm-.005-2.116l-.006-.005.006-.005.005.005-.005.005zM9.255 10.5v.008h-.008V10.5h.008zm3.249 1.88l-.007.004-.003-.007.006-.003.004.006zm-1.38 5.126l-.003-.006.006-.004.004.007-.006.003zm.007-6.501l-.003.006-.007-.003.004-.007.006.004zm1.37 5.129l-.007-.004.004-.006.006.003-.004.007zm.504-1.877h-.008v-.007h.008v.007zM9.255 18v.008h-.008V18h.008zm-3.246-1.87l-.007.004L6 16.127l.006-.003.004.006zm1.366-5.119l-.004-.006.006-.004.004.007-.006.003zM7.38 17.5l-.003.006-.007-.003.004-.007.006.004zm-1.376-5.116L6 12.38l.003-.007.007.004-.004.007zm-.5 1.873h-.008v-.007h.008v.007zM17.25 12.75a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5zm0 4.5a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5z" />
                                    </svg>

                                </span>
                                ZiFM CMS
                            </h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between flex-1 h-full ">
                        <div className="space-y-4">
                            <nav className="flex-1 space-y-2">

                                <div className='mx-4 my-8'>
                                    <Link to="/cms/newscorner">
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-full px-4 py-3 text-sm font-semibold leading-5 text-white transition-all 
                                            duration-200 bg-red-800 border border-transparent rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-900 hover:bg-red-900"
                                        >
                                            <svg className="w-5 h-5 mr-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 6v6m0 0v6m0-6h6m-6 0H6" />
                                            </svg>
                                            Manage News
                                        </button>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>

                                <Link to="/cms">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
                                        </svg>
                                        Dashboard
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/newscorner">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/newscorner")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 7.5h1.5m-1.5 3h1.5m-7.5 3h7.5m-7.5 3h7.5m3-9h3.375c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V18a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.25 2.25M16.5 7.5V18a2.25 2.25 0 002.25 2.25M16.5 7.5V4.875c0-.621-.504-1.125-1.125-1.125H4.125C3.504 3.75 3 4.254 3 4.875V18a2.25 2.25 0 002.25 2.25h13.5M6 7.5h3v3H6v-3z" />
                                        </svg>

                                        News Corner
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/podcasts">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/podcasts")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 18.75a6 6 0 006-6v-1.5m-6 7.5a6 6 0 01-6-6v-1.5m6 7.5v3.75m-3.75 0h7.5M12 15.75a3 3 0 01-3-3V4.5a3 3 0 116 0v8.25a3 3 0 01-3 3z" />
                                        </svg>

                                        Podcasts
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/liveradio">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/liveradio")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 7.5l16.5-4.125M12 6.75c-2.708 0-5.363.224-7.948.655C2.999 7.58 2.25 8.507 2.25 9.574v9.176A2.25 2.25 0 004.5 21h15a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V9.574c0-1.067-.75-1.994-1.802-2.169A48.329 48.329 0 0012 6.75zm-1.683 6.443l-.005.005-.006-.005.006-.005.005.005zm-.005 2.127l-.005-.006.005-.005.005.005-.005.005zm-2.116-.006l-.005.006-.006-.006.005-.005.006.005zm-.005-2.116l-.006-.005.006-.005.005.005-.005.005zM9.255 10.5v.008h-.008V10.5h.008zm3.249 1.88l-.007.004-.003-.007.006-.003.004.006zm-1.38 5.126l-.003-.006.006-.004.004.007-.006.003zm.007-6.501l-.003.006-.007-.003.004-.007.006.004zm1.37 5.129l-.007-.004.004-.006.006.003-.004.007zm.504-1.877h-.008v-.007h.008v.007zM9.255 18v.008h-.008V18h.008zm-3.246-1.87l-.007.004L6 16.127l.006-.003.004.006zm1.366-5.119l-.004-.006.006-.004.004.007-.006.003zM7.38 17.5l-.003.006-.007-.003.004-.007.006.004zm-1.376-5.116L6 12.38l.003-.007.007.004-.004.007zm-.5 1.873h-.008v-.007h.008v.007zM17.25 12.75a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5zm0 4.5a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5z" />
                                        </svg>

                                        Live Radio
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/teammembers">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/teammembers")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z" />
                                        </svg>
                                        Team Members (Users)
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/notifications">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/notifications")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
                                        </svg>
                                        Notifications
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/accountsettings">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/accountsettings")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path
                                                stroke-linecap="round"
                                                stroke-linejoin="round"
                                                d="M10.325 4.317c.426-1.756 2.924-1.756 3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 002.573 1.066c1.543-.94 3.31.826 2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 001.065 2.572c1.756.426 1.756 2.924 0 3.35a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.066 2.573c.94 1.543-.826 3.31-2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.572 1.065c-.426 1.756-2.924 1.756-3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.573-1.066c-1.543.94-3.31-.826-2.37-2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.065-2.572c-1.756-.426-1.756-2.924 0-3.35a1.724 1.724 0 001.066-2.573c-.94-1.543.826-3.31 2.37-2.37.996.608 2.296.07 2.572-1.065z"
                                            />
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z" />
                                        </svg>
                                        Account Settings
                                    </a>
                                </Link>

                                <Link to="/cms/logout">
                                    <a title="" className={`flex items-center px-4 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-all duration-200 mt-2 hover:bg-gray-700 group ${setBgColor("/cms/logout")}`}>
                                        <svg className="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-6a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 007.5 21h6a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15M12 9l-3 3m0 0l3 3m-3-3h12.75" />
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-6a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 007.5 21h6a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15M12 9l-3 3m0 0l3 3m-3-3h12.75" />
                                        </svg>
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
                                </Link>
                            </nav>

                            {/* <hr className="border-gray-700" /> */}
                        </div>

                        {/* <div className="sideBarAnalyticsCard mx-4 text-center mt-10">
                            <Sidebarcard />
                        </div> */}

                        <div className="px-5 pb-8 mt-8">
                            <div className="flex items-center space-x-6">
                                <a href="#" title="" className="text-xs font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white"> Privacy Policy </a>
                                <a href="#" title="" className="text-xs font-medium text-gray-400 hover:text-white"> Terms of Service </a>
                            </div>
                            <p className="mt-4 text-xs font-medium text-gray-400">© 2023 ZiFM CMS</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
                <main>
                    <div className="py-6">
                        <div className="px-4 mx-auto max-w-7xl sm:px-6 md:px-8">
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AccountLayout
```

Comment: Have you tried "fixed" position ?

Comment: yes i have but its not working

Comment: I would probably split the screen into two columns. And put the left column with position: fixed and the rigth column with overflow-y: auto. And if you do this change in your css you could also delete the first div that make background grey and just put the background color on the body element.